# Datazen, provide windows user access

Tags: datazen-server

I am looking for a way to assign a windows user/group access to a hub or Datazen dashboard, similar to the way in SSRS we can assign user/group access on a report or report folder.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul,

First, you either need to be the admin to the server or have "IS OWNER" permissions to a hub to be able to carry out any admin tasks such as adding users or assigning permissions.

Now, things are a little different in datazen from SSRS, at least for now, this might change after SQL Server 2016 release where datazen will be integrated with SQL Server and will be called Mobile Reports.

I am assuming you have already created users in Datazen and would like to assign them to a group and give group access/permissions.

-Click on the Hub name you would like to go to.
-Click on "User Groups" in left hand panel.
-Click on "Create New User Group" located on top right of the screen.
-Enter Group Name
(the group you created will appear after you create it)
- Click on "Users..." option for that Group.
- Check all the users that need to be assigned to that group.

- Click on "Permissions" in left hand panel.

(Dashboards option is selected by default. You could either select a single dashboard or the dashboard group folder in the drop down box labeled "Dashboards & Dashboard Groups")

- Select User Group/Users option in drop down box labeled "Set permissions for:"
- Check the box next to the group that needs to be allowed access to.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no possibility to add a windows user group in Datazen.

Datazen has a different paradigm as SSRS.

The only way is to create "local" groups in datazen as Maraduarz already wrote.

Best Regards

Daniel